# Position:absolute element being hidden behind later elements

Tags: css, position, hidden, absolute

I've put together a jsfiddle to illustrate my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ABkjE/).  Essentially, I've got an absolutely-positioned menu system above my main content, but the content seems to be floating in front of the menus.  Hover over "Link 3" to see that it's just the main content that's hiding it; the menus show up below when they're long enough.

My nav-header looks something like this:

```
<div id='nav-header'>
    <div class='nav-bar'>
        <div class='nav-item '>
            <a class='link-3' href='#'>
                <div class='nav-text-container'><p>Link 3</p></div>
            </a>
            <div class='flydown-container link-3'>
                <div class='flydown'>
                    <div class='header'>Heading 1</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 3</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 4</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 5</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class='header'>Heading 2</div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class='secondary-menu-link' href='#'><span>Sub-link 3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's quite a bit of CSS, it's all at that jsfiddle link above.

Comment: try taking off the `position: relative;` from `#media-slider`. works for me

Comment: @RicardoArruda Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `z-index` CSS property (stacking level).  Lower z-index means lower stacking context (so if two overlapping sibling elements have different z-indices, the one with the higher z-index will display on top).

Note that z-index establishes a new stacking context for each level of elements so they need to be on the same level of the DOM.  Also, z-index only works on positioned elements so it won't do anything unless you set them to relative, absolute or fixed position.

Fixed your code:

```
#nav-header {
    width: 940px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
#upper-section {
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

More z-index info: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: "Also, z-index only works on positioned elements so it won't do anything unless you set them to relative, absolute or fixed position." 

Yes!! Sweet action! This was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `position: relative;` in the `#media-slider` , if you dont have a purpose to use this property, remove and will work.

Comment: Not quite.  It appears to work, but adding a style of `background-color: blue;` to `.media-container` reveals that the menu is still being hidden.