# Why is my hamburger menu hidden behind my container?

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar

Why does my menu stay hidden behind my main container and can only been seen through scrolling?

I've tried things like increasing the z-index and changing the positioning type, but it only seems to work when I increase the *min-height* of *nav-container*.

I've tried to increase the height of the *nav-container* with *onClick* event listeners and [React hooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#React_hooks), but I'm not sure if it's the right way to go.

How could I overcome this?

Here is my CSS code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1050px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 3px solid red;
  background-color: wheat;
  z-index: 30;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.navContainer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div style={{ minHeight: hover ? '100vh' : 'auto'}}
     ref={containerRef} className={`${HamburgerCSS.container} ${HamburgerCSS.navContainer}` }>

    <input ref={inputRef} onChange={checkedOrNot} className={HamburgerCSS.checkbox} type="checkbox" name="" id="" />

    <div className={HamburgerCSS.hamburgerLines}>
        <span onClick={handleClick} className={`${HamburgerCSS.line} ${HamburgerCSS.line1}`} />

        <span className={`${HamburgerCSS.line} ${HamburgerCSS.line2}`} />
        <span className={`${HamburgerCSS.line} ${HamburgerCSS.line3}`} />
    </div>

    <div className={HamburgerCSS.logo}>
        <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </div>

    <div className={HamburgerCSS.menuItems}>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">blogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at your code, It is hard to tell where you problem is, because you code snippet is missing HamburgerCSS. In cases like this try to host your code online in platforms like codesandbox.io with the minimum code to reproduce your problem. Paste a link to it here, so people can open it and try to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Yes, I've now created a codesandbox and everything seems to be working fine on that platform but in VS code all I get is a scroll bar and part of the rolled out menu covered up by the body. Do you think this could be class name clashing or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely happening because you are either using a third party library for you hamburger menu or you are using absolute positioning for you hamburger menu or it's container. You might want to checkout this article on absolute positioning and you also might want to read this
[1]: [Position:absolute element being hidden behind later elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982073/positionabsolute-element-being-hidden-behind-later-elements)